# How to use Unicode chars with Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I want to use Unicode char with `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment`.

```
frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("<foo>ü</foo>")
=> <foo>&#xFC;</foo>
```

The unicode char is escaped. I need to set `encoding: 'UTF-8'` to get a readable char.

```
frag.to_html(encoding: 'UTF-8')
=> "<foo>ü</foo>"
```

Is there a option for encoding when parsing the string?

`Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse` treat the string as I expected, but I need to use `XML`.

```
frag = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<foo>ü</foo>")
=> <foo>ü</foo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#encoding) the text is internally stored as UTF-8 already.

> Strings are always stored as UTF-8 internally. Methods that return text values will always return UTF-8 encoded strings. Methods that return XML (like to_xml, to_html and inner_html) will return a string encoded like the source document.

So if you call for example `#text` on your `frag` instead of printing the entire `frag` object, you'll see the ü printed correctly

```rb
puts frag.text
# => ü
```

Otherwise you can use `#XML` instead of `#DocumentFragment` directly and pass the encoding explicitly.

```rb
doc = Nokogiri.XML('<foo>ü</foo>', nil, 'UTF-8')
puts doc

# => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# => <foo>ü</foo>
```